# What can i do ?E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gophers/archive/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, amd-ryzen, linux-headers, golang, amavisd-new

```
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gophers/archive/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found 
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gophers/archive/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party software repositories, with all security checks on you to perform. Did you perform any checks?  That PPA was abandoned in 2019 thus expecting it to support a release from 2020 makes no sense.  (ie. https://launchpad.net/~gophers/+archive/ubuntu/archive  which was taken from your pasted details)